# Using fleqn option in a new LaTeX class

Tags: math-mode, spacing, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I am creating a new LaTeX class, necessarily the equations must be aligned to the left so I use the file `fleqn.clo` in the class code. The problem is that when using the equation environment the result equation is well constructed but not appears any space between it and the paragraphs, like as if the equation be a normal paragraph. This is different to what happens when using the `article` class with `fleqn` option, and basically the article class does the same thing that me when including `fleqn.clo`.

I think important part of the code I wrote

```
%Load Packages
\RequirePackage[letterpaper,twocolumn,twoside,includeheadfoot,driver=auto,
                text={17.59cm,22.94cm},top=2.5cm,inner=2.5cm,outer=1.5cm,columnsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[spanish,english]{babel}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}


%Declarations
\DeclareOption{spanish}{%
    \AtBeginDocument{\selectlanguage{spanish}}
}
\DeclareOption{english}{%
    \AtBeginDocument{\selectlanguage{english}}
}
\DeclareOption*{\ClassWarning{RCIULApaper}{Unknown `\CurrentOption', default language used is spanish}}
\ExecuteOptions{spanish}
\ProcessOptions\relax

%Align equations to left
\input{fleqn.clo}
\renewcommand \theequation {\@arabic\c@equation}

%Set the document font size
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\@setfontsize{\normalsize}{10}{12.00pt}}%
\normalsize
\abovedisplayskip 1.5ex plus4pt minus2pt%
\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip%
\abovedisplayshortskip 1.5ex plus4pt minus2pt%
\belowdisplayshortskip 1.5ex plus4pt minus2pt
\newcommand{\tiny}{\@setfontsize{\tiny}{5}{6pt}}
\newcommand{\scriptsize}{\@setfontsize{\scriptsize}{7}{8pt}}
\newcommand{\footnotesize}{\@setfontsize{\footnotesize}{8}{10pt}}
\newcommand{\small}{\@setfontsize{\small}{8.5}{10pt}}
\newcommand{\large}{\@setfontsize{\large}{12}{12pt}}
\newcommand{\Large}{\@setfontsize{\Large}{14}{14.40pt}}
\newcommand{\LARGE}{\@setfontsize{\LARGE}{18}{18pt}}
\newcommand{\huge}{\@setfontsize{\huge}{20}{20.74pt}}
\newcommand{\Huge}{\@setfontsize{\Huge}{24}{24.88pt}}

%Using Times Roman font 
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

%Tolerances
\hyphenpenalty=750
\hbadness=2200
\binoppenalty=1000
\relpenalty=800
```

What should I add to have a good behavior?

[image: The problem, display style vs the equation environment]

Thanks!

Comment: You're setting `\abovedisplaysshortskip` to `0pt` (plus some glue). You may notice that if your paragraph ends with a short line, this is a problem, but it the paragraph has a long ending line, then it's not a problem. Is this the case?

Comment: Thanks @Werner but nothing changes by placing a different value for `\abovedisplayshortskip`. Also the _article_ class does not use any configuration of these commands, just use `\input{fleqn.clo}` and `\renewcommand \theequation {\@arabic\c@equation}`, wherefore I failed to find the solution based on the existent class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fleqn` doesn't use displaymath it is a `trivlist` so the vertical spacing is governed by `\topsep` `\partopsep` and the other list parameters. You presumably have these set to 0 in your class?

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\begin{document}


\noindent aaaaaaaa\[1=2\]bbbbbbbbbbb

\topsep0pt
\partopsep0pt
\parsep0pt
\parskip0pt

\noindent aaaaaaaa\[1=2\]bbbbbbbbbbb


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle I put the complete code for you to see, `\topsep` is never used, however, had already tried some value for it and work, but this affects other environments like `center`, I just wanted to know what I can do to affect only the `equation` environment.

Comment: The displaystyle works perfectly with the settings for `\abovedisplayskip` and the others.

Comment: I upload an image where see the problem, and the use of $$ for display a equation without numbering.

Comment: @osjerick The value of `\topsep` after loading the class is 0pt and this, as David says, explains the issue. You can cure it by loading also `\RequirePackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`. However you should also set sensible values for `\topsep` and the other list parameters.

Comment: Well, I accept this as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Ok! Thanks @egreg, works perfectly with `\RequirePackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`.